# Symfony, loading a role from another table, from an associated ID in the user

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine

ok, I will start of with my db layout, I have a `access_levels_id` in my `Users` table, which I want to load my role based on each user.

Now this is as far as I have got but I am not getting it to work,

My ORM, which the profiler dose not have any issues with,

```
Users Tables :

    manyToOne:
    accesslevel:
        targetEntity: AccessLevels
        inversedBy: user
        joinColumn:
            name: access_levels_id
            referencedColumnName: id
```

Access Table :

```
    oneToMany:
    user:
        targetEntity: Users
        mappedBy: accesslevel
```

This dose short of work, what I do to see the `User`

```
public function BlogAction() {
     $user = $this->getUser();

     var_dump( $user ); //see below to see what this returns

     return $this->render('xxxxxxxx.html.twig');
}

var dump

private 'accesslevel' => 
 object(Proxies\__CG__\xx\Entity\AccessLevels)[236]
  public '__initializer__' => 
    object(Closure)[234]
      public 'static' => 
        array (size=2)
          ...
      public 'this' => 
        object(Doctrine\ORM\Proxy\ProxyFactory)[132]
          ...
      public 'parameter' => 
        array (size=1)
          ...
  public '__cloner__' => 
    object(Closure)[235]
      public 'static' => 
        array (size=2)
          ...
      public 'this' => 
        object(Doctrine\ORM\Proxy\ProxyFactory)[132]
          ...
      public 'parameter' => 
        array (size=1)
          ...
  public '__isInitialized__' => boolean false
  private 'id' (xx\Entity\AccessLevels) => int 3
  private 'level' (xx\Entity\AccessLevels) => null
  private 'leveltitle' (xx\Entity\AccessLevels) => null
```

So why, given that its got the right ID on AccessLevel, if I change this, it updates, so why is `level` and `leveltitle` empty?

What I have also tried, in my `Access Levels` entity, dose implement `RoleInterface`, and I have been doing this in my `Users` entity,

```
public function getRoles()
{
    $UserLevel = $this->getAccessLevelsId();
    return array('ROLE_ADMIN', new AccessLevels($UserLevel));
}
```

And in my `Access Level` entity, I do this,

```
private $UsersLevel;

public function __construct($UsersLevel) {

    $this->UsersLevel = $UsersLevel;
}

public function getRole()
{
    $UsersRoleID =  $this->UsersLevel;

    return 'ROLE_TEST'.$UsersRoleID; <- this has the ID
    #return 'ROLE_TEST88'; 
             ^this works, and my user has admin and test88 roles
}
```

So how do I use my getters, getLeveltitle, to return the right role based on the ID from the `access_level_id` in my users table.

From what I have looked at, I would have to use `getDoctine` and query my database to get this method to work, now I think I can do that via a service/helper? But I am not sure thats the right way about going about this.

Or am I do this all wrong?

Thanks,

Comment: I think I know what the problem is. I don't think I am requesting my data right, so that its NULL due to lazy loading. Now I have done a few tests, I need to be more, when I have a solution I post it. But dose anyone know how to turn off, like force a load, on just one relationship, as the user table will have more than one. Thanks